# Comparisons with NULLs in SQL

Tags: sql, null, ansi-sql

ANSI-92 SQL mandates that comparisons with `NULL` evaluate to "falsy," eg:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = NULL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field != NULL
```

Will *both* return no rows because `NULL` can't be compared like that. Instead, the predicates `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` have to be used instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IS NULL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IS NOT NULL
```

Research has shown me that Oracle <sup>1</sup>, PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite all support the ANSI syntax. Add to that list DB2 and Firebird.

Aside from SQL Server with `ANSI_NULLS` turned off, what other RDBMS support the non-ANSI syntax?

*<sup>1</sup> The whole empty string = `NULL` mess notwithstanding.*

Comment: Oracle (11g here) does exactly as you describe in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) is a nice comparison of null handling in SQLite, PostgreSQL, Oracle, Informix, DB2, MS-SQL, OCELOT, MySQL 3.23.41, MySQL 4.0.16, Firebird, SQL Anywhere, and Borland Interbase

Answer (score 15):

For what it's worth, comparing something to NULL is not strictly false, it's *unknown*.  Furthermore, `NOT` unknown is still unknown.

ANSI SQL-99 defines a predicate `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`.  This allows you to mix nulls and non-null values in comarisons, and always get a true or false.  Null compared to null in this way is true, otherwise any non-null compared to null is false.  So negation works as you probably expect.

PostgreSQL, IBM DB2, and Firebird do support `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`.

MySQL has a similar null-safe comparison operator `<=>` that returns true if the operands are the same and false if they're different.

Oracle has the hardest path.  You have to get creative with use of `NVL()` or boolean expressions:

```
WHERE a = b OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL)
```

Yuck.

Comment: The writing between the lines is that there is no standard way to disable standard behavior.

Comment: @Daniel I wasn't looking for a standard way at all; just *any* way (like SQL Server's `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`)

Comment: I'm not aware of similar configuration options in other RDBMS.  I was just trying to suggest other solutions for doing null-safe comparisons.

Comment: If you use Bill's solution, you get the behavior you want in a standard way. If you instead find vendor-specific ways of disabling standard behavior and do that, you get code that's doubly unportable: once for depending on a vendor extension, and again for using the wrong kinds of comparisons in all your statements. Strongly not recommended.

Comment: afaik, the `distinct from` predicate is not exposed in LUW DB2. This is the flavor of db2 a lot of people see.

Comment: You can also use DECODE with Oracle: WHERE DECODE(a,b,1)=1